# Laravel call a function after view is rendered

Tags: php, laravel, view

I am working on a laravel website that has the basic functionality of searching for flights/hotels etc..
One thing I want to do is show a loading page after the user submits the search information so that some animation is happening while the API runs.

Problem is I can't figure out a way to show the page and run the controller code at the same time. I've been trying from my PagesController to pass the FlightsController to the view

> PagesController.php

```
public function flight_search( Request $request )
{

    $FlightsController = new FlightsController();

    return view('flights.flight-search', [
        'FlightsController' => $FlightsController,
        'user_input' => $request
        ]);
}
```

and then calling the function in the flight-search view like so

> flight-search.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="page-heading">Searching for available tickets...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-warning active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{ $FlightsController->search( $user_input ) }}

@endsection
```

But the page load always waits for the function call to finish to complete, and the search() method itself returns the next view with the search result.

Any suggestions on how I should proceed with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server will send the response only after the whole request is processed so what you're trying to do won't work. A common solution to do that is to show the loading screen, send AJAX request to the server to fetch the result and, once the results are loaded, hide the loading screen and show the result. Of course this has to be done with Javascript, not PHP.

So the scenario would be:

- user fills the form
- user clicks "Search"
- show loading screen with Javascript
- send AJAX request to the backend to get the result with Javascript
- when results are fetched, hide the loading screen and show the results with Javascript

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was hoping to find a way to do it with only Laravel but sadly the request processing doesn't allow that. Thanks for the detailed reply !